# SDL Web 8 JS Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLoaded' of undefined

Tags: web8, upgrade, javascript, chrome, adamtridionconnector

Looks like in Chrome `Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)`, post `2013` to `Web 8.1.1` upgrade has some js issues which are not allowing me to open components that have media associated to them.

Also, notice overall slowness reported from editorial team for mundane tasks like browsing, opening and associating and when saving components in Chrome, it leaves them in checked-out state.

[image]

Does anyone else experience the same with Chrome or these js errors when trying to open a component, possibly of a certain type or with multi-media assets or media from DAM system associated?

Comment: The JavaScript errors are probably due to issues on the server side, causing data not to load correctly on the client. Are there any errors in the Event Log? Make sure you also check for warnings from ASP.NET in the Application log (in addition to anything in the Tridion log)

Comment: @Andrew William Ross:  updated all namespace as per sdlweb 8.1.1 standard? I think .js reference files or configuration missing. Please debuge and check..

Comment: @Sudhakar indeed it was a namespace issue, not only in the schemas, but then needed to resynch components and correct the namespace of the components as well in the source. I didn't know this was a sdlweb 8.1.1 standard.. Where did you find that info?

Comment: Thanks, Please debug and check the line 1040.
Tridion.Web.UI.CME.Commands.Publishing.ViewSite._isEnabled (WebUI/Editors/CME/Component/Component_V8.1.0.194.10_.aspx?mode=js:1040) Please share you schema design structure to replicate this issue.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamRoss Please update this question with what needed to change so you can mark this with a resolved answer to help others!

Comment: @RobStevenson-Leggett Thanks for checking up on this. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the component with Dev tools enabled, could see this invalid markup character at the end of the namespace:

```
 error on line 1 at column 67: xmlns: 'http://site.domain.com/folderPath/DescriptionKeyï»¿' is not a valid URI
```

This was not seen by the naked eye when you view the namespace that was updated in the schema source.

I later found out, that this was copy + paste from a Confluence site which is like word and contains markup/markdown when I inquired about the update.

Further, we had to go into each component; and not only save and close each component to take the updates from the schema change, but also **update the namespace in each component source**. Each namespace in the source contained "extra spaces" that you couldn't see unless you started to backspace before the end of the double quotes in each namespace reference.

Hope this helps. It was a bugger!